# Java prevent calling private or protected methods outside of class

Tags: java, reflection, private

Let's supppose that I have created a Java library, called `Foo` and I have a class inside that library called `Bar`. Let's suppose further that in the `Bar` class I have a private method, called `fooBar`.

```
public class Bar {
    //...
    private Object fooBar() {
        //Do something
    }
    //...
}
```

One can run this method without any difficulties with a code written in a class, like this:

```
public static Object runMethod(Object object, String methodName) {
    Method method = object.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    return method.invoke(object);
}
```

However, let us suppose that we intend to discourage this habit for `fooBar`. How can we do something like that? Should we get the stack trace from somewhere and check where it was called? Or should we do something else?

Comment: You've already discouraged people to call your method by making it private.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a security manager...

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html

> A security manager is an object that defines a security policy for an
>   application. This policy specifies actions that are unsafe or
>   sensitive. Any actions not allowed by the security policy cause a
>   SecurityException to be thrown. An application can also query its
>   security manager to discover which actions are allowed.

It supports disallowing `setAccessible()` to make private and protected methods invocable via reflection.

Answer (score 3):

I think if you want to be extreme, you could get the stack trace like this:

```
public class Bar {
    //...
    private Object fooBar() {
        try {
            throw new CheckIfCalledFromMethodException(); 
        } catch(CheckIfCalledFromMethodException e) {
            //here you have access to stack trace in your exception
        }

        //Do something
    }
    //...
}
```

I put together a simple scenario in which it checks if the `second` instance that calls the class is the same object or something else.

```
public class StackTraceTest {
    private void execute() {
        try {
            throw new Exception();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            /*for(int i = 0; i < e.getStackTrace().length; i++) {
                StackTraceElement stackTraceElement = e.getStackTrace()[i];
                System.out.println(stackTraceElement.getFileName());
            }
            System.out.println("");
            e.printStackTrace();*/
            if(!e.getStackTrace()[1].getFileName().equals(StackTraceTest.class.getSimpleName() + ".java")) {
                throw new IllegalAccessError("Illegal Access.");
            }
        }
    }

    public void executeExternal() {
        this.execute();
    }
}
```

And

```
public class AccsessorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        StackTraceTest stackTraceTest = new StackTraceTest();
        stackTraceTest.executeExternal();
        System.out.println("Accessed from within other method in class.");
        System.out.println("");
        Class<?> clazz = StackTraceTest.class;
        Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("execute");
        method.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println("Accessing through reflection...");
        method.invoke(stackTraceTest);
    }
}
```

Then I get

```
Accessed from within other method in class.

Reflection test start.
Accessing through reflection...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at stacktracetest.another.AccsessorTest.main(AccsessorTest.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Illegal Access.
    at stacktracetest.StackTraceTest.execute(StackTraceTest.java:18)
    ... 10 more
```

So I guess it is possible to check with stack trace element magic, but you should check if this actually works, this is extremely rough and I've just put it together a second ago.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer, as it should work. However, it was clearly the solution I was thinking about as well. I have asked my question in the hope that there is something better. Phil Anderson's answer however is clearly superior to this idea. I have upvoted that one as well and I accept it.

Comment: Indeed, but I was curious to see it in action in case one doesn't have the authority to set the SecurityManager, etc.

Comment: No problems, I believe your answer is a good one, I have been suggesting the same thing in my question and it is nice to write an answer illustrating an idea. Certainly deserves the up-vote, however, we have to acknowledge that the other answer is superior and this one is a work-around when the other solution is not available for a reason.